# How can I write strings and matrices to a .txt file in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, file-io, text-files

I need to write data to a .txt file in MATLAB. I know how to write strings (`fprintf`) *or* matrices (`dlmwrite`), but I need something that can do both of them. I'll give an example below:

```
str = 'This is the matrix: ' ;
mat1 = [23 46 ; 56 67] ;
%fName
if *fid is valid* 
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str)
    fclose(fid)
end
dlmwrite(fName, *emptymatrix*, '-append', 'delimiter', '\t', 'newline','pc')
dlmwrite(fName, mat1, '-append', 'newline', 'pc')
```

This works okay, but with a problem. The first line of the file is:

```
This is the matrix: 23,46
```

Which is not what I want. I want to see:

```
This is the matrix:
23 46
56 67
```

How can I solve this? I can't use a for loop and `printf` solution as the data is huge and time is an issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think all you have to do to fix your problem is add a carriage return (`\r`) to your [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) statement and remove the first call to [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html):

```
str = 'This is the matrix: ';      %# A string
mat1 = [23 46; 56 67];             %# A 2-by-2 matrix
fName = 'str_and_mat.txt';         %# A file name
fid = fopen(fName,'w');            %# Open the file
if fid ~= -1
  fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',str);       %# Print the string
  fclose(fid);                     %# Close the file
end
dlmwrite(fName,mat1,'-append',...  %# Print the matrix
         'delimiter','\t',...
         'newline','pc');
```

And the output in the file looks like this (with tabs between the numbers):

```
This is the matrix: 
23  46
56  67
```

**NOTE:** A short explanation... the reason for needing the `\r` in the [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) statement is because a PC line terminator is comprised of a carriage return followed by a line feed, which is what is used by [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) when the `'newline','pc'` option is specified. The `\r` is needed to ensure the first line of the matrix appears on a new line when opening the output text file in Notepad.

Comment: Thanks gnovice! u have helped me again!

Comment: I have a related Q: 
The code works correctly on my system.  But when I remote desktop to a server and set its Matlab path to my local matlab-directories, the same code fails to set up the file.  The whole projects runs correctly, but file procedure is failing. Any comments?  Thanks

Comment: pathstr = 'C:/Documents and Settings/xxx/My Documents/MATLAB/Factor Production/Results/xxx' ;
This path works fine when I execute it locally.  However, when I use a server and run the same group of files (by setting path), this fails. I get error "No such file or directory".

The message is from the code line: [fid,message] = fopen(fName,'w') ;

Comment: thanks. I just output the results to another server.  It serves the purpose well! appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the empty matrix call.  Try this code:

```
str = 'This is the matrix: ' ;
mat1 = [23 46 ; 56 67] ;
fName = 'output.txt';
fid = fopen('output.txt','w');
if fid>=0
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str)
    fclose(fid)
end
dlmwrite(fName, mat1, '-append', 'newline', 'pc', 'delimiter','\t');
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got two dlmwrite() calls, the first on an empty matrix, and the second one is missing the 'delimiter' option. What happens if you add it to the second call?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation adding a header to a csv. You can use dlmwrite with -append to add a single line by setting your delimiter equal to `''` as shown below.

```
str = 'This is the matrix: ';      %# A string
mat1 = [23 46; 56 67];             %# A 2-by-2 matrix
fName = 'str_and_mat.txt';         %# A file name
header1 = 'A, B'
dlmwrite(fName, str, 'delimiter', '')
dlmwrite(fName, header1, '-append', 'delimiter', '')
dlmwrite(fName, mat1, '-append','delimiter', ',')
```

This produces the following:

```
This is the matrix: 
A, B
23,46
56,67
```