# How can I append a cell array to a .txt file?

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files, cell-array

I previously queried about [including matrices and strings in a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556971/writing-to-a-txt-file-in-matlab-strings-matrices-cells). I now need to append cells to it. From my prior question:

```
str = 'This is the matrix: ';
mat1 = [23 46; 56 67];
fName = 'output.txt';
fid = fopen(fName, 'w');
if fid >= 0
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);
    fclose(fid);
end
dlmwrite(fName, mat1, '-append', 'newline', 'pc', 'delimiter', '\t');
```

Now I want to append a string: '*The removed identifiers are*' and then this cell array below it:

```
'ABC' [10011] [2]
'DEF' [10023] [1]
```

Some relevant links:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileformats.html, http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1CCMDO/index.html?solution=1-1CCMDO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use functions like [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) or [CSVWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvwrite.html) for writing cell arrays of data. However, to get the output you want you can still use a single call to [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html), but you will have to specify the format of all the entries in a row of your cell array. Building on [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556971/writing-to-a-txt-file-in-matlab-strings-matrices-cells/4557188#4557188), you would add these additional lines:

```
str = 'The removed identifiers are: ';   %# Your new string
cMat = {'ABC' 10011 2; 'DEF' 10023 1};   %# Your cell array
fid = fopen(fName,'a');                  %# Open the file for appending
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',str);               %# Print the string
cMat = cMat.';                          %'# Transpose cMat
fprintf(fid,'%s\t%d\t%d\r\n',cMat{:});   %# Print the cell data
fclose(fid);                             %# Close the file
```

And the new file contents (including the old example) will look like this:

```
This is the matrix: 
23  46
56  67
The removed identifiers are: 
ABC 10011   2
DEF 10023   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [cellwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7363-cellwrite) from *File Exchange*. Reading [Writing Mixed Data With MATLAB](http://francisbarnhart.com/blog/2005/01/19/matlab_pain/) from *Francis Barnhart*, the creator of cellwrite might be worth a look.

It should be a feasible task, to change cellwrite's signature to accept a file handle. Allowing to append data to an already existing file.