# How to save in a txt multiple Matlab vectors

Tags: matlab, io

I am working on a piece of code where points are plotted using the following command:

```
plot3(X(1:s,1),X(1:s,2),X(1:s,4),'.');
```

What is the best way to save the data? I tried with

```
save('File.txt','X(1:s,1),X(1:s,2),X(1:s,4)','.');
```

But I get the error `'X(1:s,1),X(1:s,2),X(1:s,4)' is not a valid variable name`

Comment: I think you have a bug? Maybe you wanted to say `'X(1:s,1)','X(1:s,2)','X(1:s,4)'`? If that doesn't work, you can just try to save them first separately, `x1 = X(1:s,1)`, `x2 = X(1:s,2)`, `x4=X(1:s,4)`.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your suggestion. I followed your suggestion and introduced a for loop (code below). It is still not working; do you spot any obvious mistake? `X1 = X(1:s,1);
X2 = X(1:s,2);
X4 = X(1:s,4);
%save('Omega_and_p.txt','X1','X2','X4');
for j = 1:s
    A(j,1:3) = [X(j,1);X(j,2);X(j,4)];
    save('Data.txt','A(j,:)','.');
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556971/writing-to-a-txt-file-in-matlab-strings-matrices-cells?rq=1), this is a possible way to save data from a matrix:

```
A(1:s,1) = X(1:s,1);
A(1:s,2) = X(1:s,2);
A(1:s,3) = X(1:s,4);
fName = 'Omega_and_p.txt';
fid = fopen('Omega_and_p.txt','w');
if fid>=0
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n')
    fclose(fid)
end
dlmwrite(fName, A, '-append', 'newline', 'pc', 'delimiter','\t');
```